# drop down hide behind jquery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[image]

how to display custom drop down on top of slider as per below image

i have used below link for slider

http://www.bitrepository.com/content-sliders.html

and for drop down, i have used below link

http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/f649279c-dc3a-42cb-ab10-e24ae9a1bb90/?Stylish%20Dropdown%20in%20HTML

any suggestion will be appreciated.
Please help me!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like either a `z-index` or an `overflow:hidden;` issue, without being able to look at the code itself.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the demo of the slider you are using i think the problem is in `<div id="featured">` because it has css property `overflow:hidden` so anything outside that div 'll not be seen.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Adrift said I think it will be better if you provide Fiddle demonstrating your problem. If you can't then for your dropdown like

```
<div><!-- You content slider main DIV -->
   <select style="position: relative; z-index: 1000;"></select>
</div>
```

You can use class instead if you do not like to use inline style.